# Pointer not being set to NULL (C)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, null

I'm trying to figure out how to set a struct pointer to NULL within a function.  Here is my code.

```
struct object
{
    char* name;
    int type;
};

struct object* createObject(char* new_name, int new_type)
{
    struct object* new_object = (struct object*) malloc(sizeof(struct object));

    new_object->name = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(new_name) + 1));

    strcpy(new_object->name, new_name);
    new_object->type = new_type;

    return new_object;
}

void freeData(struct object* clearedObject)
{
    free(clearedObject->name);
    clearedObject->name = NULL;
    clearedObject->type = 0;
}

void freeObject(struct object* deadObject)
{
    free(deadObject);
    deadObject = NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct object* my_object = createObject("Test", 1234);

    printf("Pointer to Object: %p\n", my_object);
    printf("Pointer to Name  : %p\n", my_object->name);
    printf("Name: %s\n", my_object->name);
    printf("Type: %d\n", my_object->type);
    printf("\n");

    freeData(my_object);

    printf("Pointer to Object: %p\n", my_object);
    printf("Pointer to Name  : %p\n", my_object->name);
    printf("Name: %s\n", my_object->name);
    printf("Type: %d\n", my_object->type);
    printf("\n");

    freeObject(my_object);

    printf("Pointer to Object: %p\n", my_object);
}
```

This is what the code outputs:

```
Pointer to Object:  005E17B8
Pointer to Name  :  005E17D8
Name:  Test
Type:  1234

Pointer to Object:  005E17B8
Pointer to Name  :  00000000
Name:  (null)
Type:  0

Pointer to Object:  005E17B8
```

Why can I set the pointer to the struct's name to NULL within a function, but not the actual struct pointer itself?  How can this be done?
I need to set my_object to NULL from within the function, how would this be possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the function the following way

```
void freeObject(struct object ** deadObject)
{
    free( *deadObject);
    *deadObject = NULL;
}
```

And call it like

```
freeObject( &my_object );
```

The problem with your original function is that the parameter is a local variable of the function. Any changes of a local variable does not influence on the original argument.

Comment: I'm sure you meant to wrap that all in a `if (deadObject != NULL) { ... }` block. :)

Comment: @John Hascall You are wrong. I did not mean It is a question of a design. For example standard C string functions do not check whether a pointer is equal to NULL.

Comment: Holding up the standard C str* functions as an example of proper software design is very humorous.

Comment: @John Hascall it depends on your qualification. For me it is not humorous bat a question of a design. It might be a low level function for example.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  Thank you for that.  That makes sense.  I forgot that the pointer was going to be local.